# How to convert a string to plain text?

Tags: python

I've started learning Python, and now trying to convert a string (this is the mail) to plain text, but some for reason all I get either "thisisthemail" or "('this', 'is', 'the', 'mail')" if use str.split().

```
async def sendmessage(ctx, UserID: str, *Mail: str):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(
        executable_path='C://geckodriver//geckodriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://127.0.0.1/account=login')
    driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("stackoverflow") #credentials
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("stackoverflow") #credentials
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Log In']").submit()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.get('https://127.0.0.1/admin=sendmsg&id=' + UserID) #heading to the user's page
    driver.find_element_by_name("messageuser").send_keys(*Mail) #composing the message to the user
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Save']").submit() #mail sent
    time.sleep(2) #pause to save changes
    driver.quit()
```

I expect to user to see "This is the mail" instead of "thisisthemail" or "('this', 'is', 'the', 'mail')". How I can make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shot in the dark, but I believe it's because of how you made your argument list:

```
async def sendmessage(ctx, UserID: str, *Mail: str):
```

This means `Mail` comes into the function as a list of all the extra arguments you sent into it.

you can either do

```
driver.find_element_by_name("messageuser").send_keys(' '.join(Mail))
```

Or just require that the `Mail` argument be one single string, as in

```
async def sendmessage(ctx, UserID: str, Mail: str):
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_name("messageuser").send_keys(Mail)
```

Note the lack of asterisks above.

Comment: First one is working! Thank you so much, I struggled on this for a day!